# How to overload constructor when signatures overlap?

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

Lets assume I have a constructor FooBar(String foo, String bar). Sometimes I need to create objects with only "foo" sometimes only "bar" sometimes with both.

Obvious instinct to avoid null's during object creation would be to overload constructors.
But this creates a problem of same signatures.
Eg:

```
FooBar(String foo)
FooBar(String bar)
FooBar(String foo, String bar).
```

Assuming I dont want to use builders here, is there any known alternative to avoid construction of objects without using null ? In other words prevent something like = new FooBar("foo", null) ??

Comment: If you were able to, what would you like the syntax to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provide `static` factory methods, whose names can vary and reflect the actual purpose:

```
public static FooBar createWithFooOnly(String foo) {
    FooBar fb = new FooBar();
    fb.setFoo(foo);
    return fb;
}

public static FooBar createWithBarOnly(String bar) {
    FooBar fb = new FooBar();
    fb.setBar(bar);
    return fb;
}

public static FooBar createWithFooAndBar(String foo, String Bar) {
    FooBar fb = new FooBar();
    fb.setFoo(foo);
    fb.setBar(bar);
    return fb;
}
```

You stated that you didn't want a builder, but that would be the best way to eliminate the `null`s.  This sounds like the next best way.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, can't do that. There can only be one `FooBar(String)`

What you can do is put your `String`s into context like this:

```
class FirstName {
  private final String value;
  FirstName(String value) { this.value = value; }
  String value() { return this.value; }
}
class LastName {
  private final String value;
  LastName(String value) { this.value = value; }
  String value() { return this.value; }
}
```

and then

```
class FooBar {
  FooBar(FirstName firstName) { }
  FooBar(LastName lastName) { }
  FooBar(FirstName firstName, LastName lastName) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have 2 constructor with the same signature. So apart from builder, I can only think of the below option:

```
FooBar(String value, boolean isFoo) {
  if (isFoo) {
    foo = value;
  } else {
    bar = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the already given and better solutions, you can create objects using a parameterless constructor and then selectively set fields using their setters:

```
FooBar fb = new FooBar();
fb.setFoo(String foo);
```

or

```
FooBar fb = new FooBar();
fb.setBar(String bar);
```

or

```
FooBar fb = new FooBar();
fb.setFoo(String foo);
fb.setBar(String bar);
```

Note that this method has few shortcomings of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use a constructor with an `Enum` argument which indicates whether the String if for foo or bar. So, if you called `new Foobar("xyz", ArgType.FOO)`, it would take the value "xyz" for foo variable, and if you called `new Foobar("abc", ArgType.BAR)`, it would take the value "abc" to be assigned to the bar variable.

```
Foobar(String abc, ArgType at)
{
  if(at == ArgType.FOO)
    foo = abc;
  if(at == ArgType.BAR)
    bar = abc;
}
```